# Composer: Including a custom js script via composer (then load via require.js)?

Tags: javascript, composer-php, components

I've been tackling this for hours...

When it comes to components, composer creates `require.js` and `require.css` files. I want to include my own script, so it can be loaded via the same `require.js`.

Right now, even though it detects `core.js` and puts it in `/core/libs` folder:

`libs\WootWoot\core\js\core.js`

It doesn't load via the `require.js` :(

What am I doing wrong? This is my composer.json file:

```
{
    "name": "WootWoot",
    "config": {
        "component-dir": "public_html/core/libs",
        "component-baseurl": "/core/libs"
    },
    "require": {
        "robloach/component-installer": "^0.2.3",
        "components/jquery": "^3.3",
    },
    "extra": {
        "component": {
            "script": [
                "/core/js/core.js"
             ] 
        }
    }
}
```